# Apache: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, wamp

Just installed WAMP on a Windows 7 machine.

When I go to localhost / from the localhost, everything works. But when I try to go to the machine from another computer on the local network, I get the following error message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access `/` on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 192.168.1.13 Port 80

How do I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All localhost pages via WAMP blocked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296007/all-localhost-pages-via-wamp-blocked)

Answer (score 1):

See the below question. You have to allow access through port 80 to your Apache server in `httpd.conf` by making sure you have `Listen *:80`

[How to access site running apache server over lan without internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857774/how-to-access-site-running-apache-server-over-lan-without-internet-connection)

An additional resource with items to do when you install a fresh copy of WAMP

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119754,119754

Comment: Actually, none of the suggestions have resolved my issue. This is surprising since this is a completely fresh install of WAMP 2.5

Also, if I have "Listen *:80" then the server refuses to start in the first place without any errors in apache_error.

Comment: Did you change the file as prescribed? Did you restart your server after you did it? Can you describe what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, BUT

If I have "Listen *:80" then the server refuses to start in the first place without any errors in apache_error.

Also, when I get the Forbidden 403 response, the corresponding log entry is:

[client 192.168.1.109:57077] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/

Comment: Added another resource to the answer with more items that may assist in your problem. Seems you not only need to listen to port 80 but you also need to make a few additional adjustments. Please post your configuration file if you have additional issues.

Comment: It seems that the default httpd.conf already reflects all of the points on the added resource. Also, it seems that: `<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
`
specifically denies access to the root. Basically, it's not clear where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Click on wamp icon > Apache > Apache modules > rewrite module(enable this module)