# Access localhost websites on Ubuntu webserver from other devices

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, remote-access

I read it's easy to do: just find the webserver machine ip local address and go to it from other devices.

So I found it (192.168.1.221) and tried from my smartphone. It gives me the apache "Apache ubuntu default page". Great, but if i try to access one of my local websites through "192.168.1.221/websitex" it doesn't works.

Comment: Make sure /websitex exist !

Comment: It exists for sure! It works from the host machine

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf make sure you have:

```
Listen *:80
```

And if you are using VirtualHosts then set them as given below:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
   ... 
</VirtualHost>
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857774/how-to-access-site-running-apache-server-over-lan-without-internet-connection)

Comment: Httpd.conf doesn't exist in my Apache2 version. You mean ports.conf file and, anyway, listen 80 is already active.